# Compile PHP as CLI and not as CGI

Tags: apache-2.2, php, shell

I have multiple sites ruiing on my server with php 5.2.11 and it as CGI

Now i want to install my source matrix and it needs PHP as CLI versions.

CAn anyone guide me how to do that and will that affect my other websites

as i have heard that CLI does not work with mysql but with postgresql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cli can work with anything the CGI version can.  It's just a matter of including the proper modules.

I'm uncertain which OS you are using, but most places I've seen php installed as a CGI (in some cgi-bin directory) and as a binary (/usr/bin/php, /usr/local/bin/php, or perhaps /usr/pkg/bin/php)

Comment: I am using cent OS 5.3

Comment: Does your package manager list php-cli?

Comment: It don't have any option for that using using easy apache

Comment: the php cli won't be involved with apache, as it is stand-alone.  If you do not have access to a Unix shell, then you are probably screwed.  If you do, try something like "yum install php-cli" -- it might work, I don't run linux.